# Rest: filering on Json response to save bandwidth

Tags: java, json, rest, post, design-patterns

I have a rest service, not restfull.
The module is stateless and just expose some rest endopoints: receives a request, transform it, invokes external endopints, and then compose a Json response.

The thing is that the response is quite verbose, and some of the fields are quite big.

I've been asked to provide a filtering at request level, so that the response contains only the requested data.

Just to provide an example: my exposed method is a POST, and accept an image encoded BASE64, and the response too, can contain an image, and many other fields:

```
request: { image="<here a long BASE64 encoded request>"}

response: {result="success", 
    message="it was a success", 
    responseImage="<another base64 encoded image>", 
    longArray1=[
        {first="...", second="...", third="..."},
        {first="...", second="...", third="..."},
        ....many!
    ],
    longArray2=[
        {first2="...", second2="...", third2="..."},
        {first2="...", second2="...", third2="..."},
        ....many!
    ]
}
```

What I want is avoid to reinvent the wheel. Is there a known pattern to make a query (adding something in the queryString, or in the Json request, and how) so that the consumer can choose in advance what fields to receive in response, and save bandwidth in the response?

Comment: You should provide us with what you were thinking of doing. Then it would be easier for us to say if there is a better way.

Comment: I am passing some parameters (up to 3) in the query string, and using the value for filtering the response. I'd like to implement a Filter class that collects inside a map of filters, so that when I fill the response, I have only one parameter (the filter object) and ask him if the current value must be included or not.

Comment: The thing is that some filters must operate at parameter level (like response image filter: the image is just in or out) and other at array value level ( for instance if the filter for longArray1 is FAILED_ONLY, if "first" is "FAILED" I have to show the item, if it is "PASSED" I have to hide it). It is still in development (hang actually, I have something more urgent to do)

Answer (score 0):

The idea to have a Filter class is a good one. Your Filter class should provide fields which mirror the response object and use defaults for fields which are not provided. E.g. if a user of your api does not pass any json serialized filter object in their request, they should still receive data with the default filters. Extending your example, the request would look like

```
request: { 
     image="<here a long BASE64 encoded request>",
     requestFilters:{   
     responseImage="<another base64 encoded image>", 
     longArray1={ firstFilter:"PASSED_ONLY",
            secondFilter:"FAILED_ONLY",            
            ....many!
        },
     longArray2={ // using defaults for firstFilter and secondFilter
            thirdFilter="PASSED", 
            fourthFilter="FAILED",
            ....many!
        }
     ......
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you, I did something similar, but I decided to go with a optional query string, so that there is a separation between the request (Json format, mandatory) and the filters, query string optional.